# Finding broken links in the (source tree) documents for a github project

Tags: github, hyperlink, broken-links

I'm looking for some way to find the broken links inside the html pages (markdown generated) for my github projects

I've tried using the [W3C link checker](https://validator.w3.org/checklink) but get this message:

> Error: 403 Forbidden by robots.txt

(I've tried other similar tools and have run into the same problem)

Are there any other ways (except testing the links manually of course!) that I can find out which links are broken in my github projects?

Grateful for help and with kind regards, Tord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted the support and they have told me that there is no way to do this for the source tree, (of course if the documentation was in another place like for example github pages that would be a different story)

Answer (score 0):

Because that link-checker can successfully check other links, I have to conclude that GitHub puts an exclusion in its robots.txt to prevent link-checkers from crawling their site.

Other link-checkers may work depending on the exclusion rule, but if GitHub isn't allowing a known checker from W3C, I assume most other valid ones won't work either. You might try `klinkstatus` which is in most repos (built upon KDE). If other ones don't work either, I assume GitHub doesn't want bandwidth spent on link-checkers. GitHub's support has always gotten back to me when I've made inquiries, so if you can't find info from their site, I suggest contacting their support.

Comment: Thank you for your help, using klinkstatus at least investigated some links, but wasn't able to test the links in the document itself (and didn't check on sub-pages). I'll try reaching out to the Github support. Kind Regards, Tord