# GitHub Action that identifies broken links

Tags: github-actions, web-testing, broken-links

The guides https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides do not seem to target my goal of checking for broken links.

I have mainly browsed and searched https://docs.github.com/en/actions. Could someone maybe direct me to a good starting point?

It seems with external tools, this is not desired by GitHub: [Finding broken links in the (source tree) documents for a github project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113452/finding-broken-links-in-the-source-tree-documents-for-a-github-project)

Thanks and regards

Comment: I think this question is off-topic for asking for a third-party resource... but a quick search surfaced https://github.com/marketplace/actions/broken-link-check

Comment: Or really any of [these](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=broken+link+)

Comment: I would consider this an answer, because it points me to the right starting point... and if you explain why it is off-topic, you could include that as well. Thanks @BenjaminW.

Comment: See [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: In the [tag:github-actions] it says: _Use this tag for questions regarding help on creating a workflow._ But in a sense my workflow is not coded yet. Anyway, thanks for your time @BenjaminW.

Comment: It's probably not a strict line. For example: "does anybody know if there is an action to do ..." would be more clearly off-topic than "I'm trying to do X, I'm using this action and here is my workflow, but the result is not what I want because ...", where an answer could be "use this other action instead".